# Running an Excel macro via Python (using a Mac)?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I was wondering whether it would be possible to run an excel macro via Python (using a Mac, I specify the machine because I know that most of the codes used win32., which is not for Mac users). Did someone try to figure it out?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`xlwings`](https://docs.xlwings.org). It is a well thought out python package that allows you to control an excel application from python (and vice versa). It supports both Windows and Mac. On Mac it uses [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) and [`appscript`](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) behind the scenes to communicate with the excel application.

The [xlwings documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Book.macro) gives the following example for executing an excel VBA macro from python code:

> **Examples**
>
> This VBA function:
>
> ```
> Function MySum(x, y)
>     MySum = x + y
> End Function
> ```
>
> can be accessed like this:
>
> ```
> >>> import xlwings as xw
> >>> wb = xw.books.active
> >>> my_sum = wb.macro('MySum')
> >>> my_sum(1, 2)
> 3
> ```